# How to Create two SQL tables with same (related) ID

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: **AccountLogin** & **AccountDetails**. The AccountLogin has these columns: **ID** *(Primary Key - AutoIncrement)* **USERNAME** **PASSWORD**. And The AccountDetails has: **ID** *(Primary Key - AutoIncrement - which should be the same number like AccountLogin since the details are for this user)* **FIRSTNAME LASTNAME EMAIL HOBBIES SPORTS**.

How can this be achieved please? I have MySQL and phpMyAdmin.
I have created these two tables with all their fields.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not combine the tables into one Account table?

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is a unique key for that particular record in that particular table. You should have a foreign key in your `AccountDetails` table such as `user_id`, set this up to reference `id` on your `AccountLogin` table and you have your record join.

For reference see:

[SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have both of them be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Insert into the table *with* the AUTO_INCREMENT.  Use `last_insert_id()` to find out what value was created.  Then, and only then, INSERT into the other table, using that value for its `id`.

You can have a FOREIGN KEY between them, but it is not the solution of how to INSERT.